# How can I Reuse this code Passing a ViewController name

Tags: swift, reusability, code-reuse

I am programming on swift language and I want to reuse this code passing the identifier as String and the page as the view controller name, but I am getting the error ***Use of undeclared type 'page'***, how can I achieve this? thanks

```
func toReuseSession(identifier: String, **page**: UIViewController){
            
    let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    
    guard let mainVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as? **page** else {
        return
    }
    mainVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    present(mainVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**According to your function, You should be declared a generic type of UIViewController in such a way you can achieve your output. I have modified your function in a correct syntax, You can use that:-**

```
 func toReuseSession<T:UIViewController>(identifier: String, page: T){

    let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

    guard let mainVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as? T else {
        return
    }
    mainVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    present(mainVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

**Now you can call your function like that:-**

```
 self.toReuseSession(identifier: "NewPasswordViewController", page: NewPasswordViewController())
```

*// "NewPasswordViewController" is in my case when I was checking it's working. You can change whatever ViewController wants to present.*

Comment: Sorry I have 1 more question, how about if I want to pass the modalPresentationStyle, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution with generics but you have to pass the static type in the second parameter

```
extension UIViewController {
    
    func toReuseSession<T>(identifier: String, page: T.Type) where T : UIViewController {
        
        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main)
        
        guard let mainVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as? T else {
            return
        }
        mainVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(mainVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```